# Trying to make a tkinter python app for raspbian

Tags: python, tkinter, raspbian

Stupidest question ever, I wrote a nice python script I intent to run on a Raspberry Pi, but I don't want to run it as a script I need to run it as an app, I just want to double click and it should start.
Now when I double click my_app.py it opens in Thonny and I need to click run in Thonny and then it runs, and also anyone who starts it can make changes in Thonny break it, I just want to run like an .exe app runs on windows, how do I pack it in such a way ? How do I make the script into an install-able raspbian app ? What's the library or commands I need ?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Add shebang at the beginning of the script: `#!/usr/bin/env python` and make the script executable: run `chmod a+x my_app.py` in a terminal.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create an .exe, i would recommend:
https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/

if you work in a unix environment, you can just create an Launcher, with the command:

```
python /path/to/script
```

if a user clicks on the Launcher, he runs the command and your python script with gui starts